# Add/Remove programs from freecommander

Tags: freecommander

Is it possible to open Add/Remove programs from freecommander?
Not by opening My computer?

Answer (score 0):

1. In freecommander : Settings-->Shell menu-->Add FC to context menu : tick folders and drives
2. Control panel--> folders options --> file type--> Go to Drives or Files folders, click on advanced, then set Freecommander as default.

This will set Freecommander above Windows Explorer

Comment: I can't find advanced in Drives and Folders

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

1. FreeCommander has a **toolbar icon** to see all the Control Panels:

   [image]
2. When you click on it, it pops up a menu of all your Control Panels, containing "**Add/Remove Programs**" (pre-Vista) or "**Programs and Features**" (Vista and Windows 7):

   [image]
3. Better still, although it's quite pale in the screenshot, that item has a sub-menu, which shows each of the installed programs:

   [image]

Depending on how much you've got installed, and the speed of your PC, it can take a second or two to populate these menus, but it is still very convenient.